# C# Reflection: Emitting classes to existing assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

Is it possible to use Reflection.Emit to create types in an existing assembly, or do you need to define a new dynamic assembly to be able to contain dynamic types?

Basically, I intend to read in one XML definition file which defines a class that is then instantiated multiple times and populated with the data from several other XML files. Rinse and repeat over several folders (each with a different definition file).

I also intend to use this data to dynamically build the interface to my app as well as define how the data is formatted when re-saving the data to the XML files.

Comment: Does the XML definition actually change at runtime?  Perhaps a pre-build event to do the class generation would be better in your situation?

Comment: The app should load a definition file, create classes from that definition, then load another definition file and repeat the process... The definition files might be different each time the app loads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Reflection.Emit, you must always create a new assembly.

However, one potential option is to take your existing assembly, and define the contracts as interfaces.  You can create the new assembly at runtime with Reflection.Emit, and have it define types that implement your interfaces.  Your assembly can use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to instantiate the property, dynamically generated type, and return an implementation of your (known at compile time) interface.

Comment: I think this is the answer I need, but are you basically suggesting that I use interfaces as a form of programmatic Lego blocks? Because the only other way I can think of using interfaces in this part of the project would require them to be dynamic as well...

Comment: Yes, that was the basic idea.  You need to define your contracts with interfaces, and use the dynamnic generation to "glue" your program together via the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection.Emit, you define a new assembly.