# Create fake object by interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to dynamically create fake object by interface. Every method and property of this fake object should just throw NotImplementedException. Is there any simple way how to do it only with .NET reflection API?

Comment: It seems that you need to use mock libraries. Why do you need to have class with NotImplementedException? Maybe there is better solution than using mocks.

Comment: I have one assembly with interfaces and folder full of assemblies which contains classes which implements those interfaces. So on application startup I am scaning this folder and registering all interfaces with their implementation to Castle IoC container. But there are some missing implementation so I need to generate fake class which will be only throwing exception to let me know at runtime that there is something missing. It is really big application so I don't want to create these fake classes manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castle Proxies is a neat library that generates proxy objects for interfaces at run time. All the major mocking frameworks use Castle Proxies under the hood too.

The learning curve is steeper than using something like Moq, but it may be a more appropriate fit for your needs as Moq is designed to be used specifically for unit testing so the API may be too 'noisy' for what you're after.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a mocking API such as [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). It's designed for mocking in unit tests, but it should do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) can help.

A sample code (copied from its homepage) is:

```
    using ImpromptuInterface;
    using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;

    public interface IMyInterface{

       string Prop1 { get;  }

        long Prop2 { get; }

        Guid Prop3 { get; }

        bool Meth1(int x);
   }

   //Anonymous Class
    var anon = new {
             Prop1 = "Test",
             Prop2 = 42L,
             Prop3 = Guid.NewGuid(),
             Meth1 = Return<bool>.Arguments<int>(it => it > 5)
    }

    IMyInterface myInterface = anon.ActLike<IMyInterface>();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that your only solution is to use Reflection.Emit, and that is not very simple :)
See [C# Reflection: Emitting classes to existing assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114501/24047) or [Reflection Emit](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/reflection-and-reflection-emit-in-C-Sharp/) for some more info.

Comment: Moq (as suggested in another answer) is a library using Reflection.Emit so it might be a simpler solution !